# GFCI Won't rest. shows no LED Light but has power

Tags: gfci

I have a GFCI outlet in the kitchen that shows no LED color status, cannot reset but still has power and downstream.  Also, I notice that when I plug my coffee maker on the upstream outlet between another working GFCI, when I press the reset button on the GFCI in question, I hear the coffee maker start to :jump start.  Is there a short or is it just a bad GFCI?

Comment: Are we talking about 2 gfc,on same breaker?  Shut of breaker to check.  I think the first gfci is shot .And they put 2 gfci on same circuit .Witch is fine, If so when you push reset that happens .  Have you done any electrical work before this happend?

Comment: What outlets turn off when you hit TEST on the GFCI in question?

Comment: There has been no electrical work since I purchased home brand new 10 years ago. Neither the REST nor the Test button work.  The breakers are not tripped  all outlets have power including the gfci in question. The first gfci shows green light and when I test the both gfci outlets I get a good wired condition from my gfci outlet tester. I also get a good wired condition from the regular outlet that is in between both gfci outlets and the coffee machine is plugged into.

Comment: So these two GFCI receptacles are on the same standard breaker, right? Do you know whether the circuit following the malfunctioning receptacle is connected via the load terminals of the malfunctioning receptacle or is pigtailed so the malfunctioning receptacle would not respond to a ground fault in the following circuit?

Comment: A GFCI receptacle in our kitchen is on a dedicated 20 A circuit. It has two LEDs, neither of which is lit when the receptacle is on. If I push the test button the receptacle is depowered and the lower LED is lit amber. If I switch off the breaker, the receptacle is of course depowered, and no LED comes on. If I switch the breaker back on, the receptacle is powered (no reset necessary) and no LED is lit.

Answer (score 1):

GFCI receptacles very rarely go bad. So before your run out, buy and replace a GFCI. First let's try and determine if it is bad GFCI or something else is wrong. First unplug every appliance and turn off every light on the circuit and see if the GFCI will reset. If it does reset then try plugging in and run every appliance and turn on every light one at a time. If any appliance trips the GFCI then your appliance is bad and it needs to be replaced. If turning your light on and the GFCI trips then the fixture is probably malfunctioning and needs to be repaired.

If the GFCI trips when no load is on it, then after you turn your power off, pull you receptacle out and disconnect the load side conductors of on the GFCI. Carefully turn your power on and see if your GFCI resets. If it does not reset then it may be bad, but if it does reset then you have a problem with you downstream wiring. Now you have to go through the entire circuit and check to see what is in failure.

That means you reconnect the load side conductors and remove each device in sequence and test to see when you get a trip. Once you get a trip you have isolated the problem and repairs need to be made.

It's really a step by step procedure, but it is also why when you call an electrical contractor they can't give you a set price since they don't know how long it will take find and repair the problem.

Hopefully it will just be a bad appliance or GFCI. Good luck.

Comment: Doing the first step and I went ahead and cut off the circuit that powers the GFCI in question.  It only powers 4 outlets:  The GFCI, one for the disposal, one for the coffee maker, one for the frig and another spare.  When I turn off the breaker & unplug all outlets,  The GFCI reset button doesn't reset.

Comment: Sorry, it powers 5 total outlets.

Comment: @Abraham - If you don't turn the breaker back on after you remove all of the appliances, the GFCI won't reset. Sort of like you can't take the car out of park unless your foot is on the brake.

Answer (score 0):

Dose the white wired side say line and charge if so move your coffee outlet white wires and put both whites to to corresponding holes that should fix the outlet the reason for this is a gfci is meant to be idiot proof charge is to connect the outlets connected to the gfci so if water gets in it the gfci will shut it down if there are 8 holes to put wires in put the two black wires in the holes corresponding with the first black you put it there will be 4 holes on blacks side 2 on top two on bottom use the bottom holes on both sets of holes

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's really hard to understand this; would you break it into sentences? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.